# How to test for document being undefined with RTL?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the following react hook which brings focus to a given ref and on unmount returns the focus to the previously focused element.

```
export default function useFocusOnElement(elementRef: React.RefObject<HTMLHeadingElement>) {
  const documentExists = typeof document !== 'undefined';
  const [previouslyFocusedEl] = useState(documentExists && (document.activeElement as HTMLElement));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (documentExists) {
      elementRef.current?.focus();
    }

    return () => {
      if (previouslyFocusedEl) {
        previouslyFocusedEl?.focus();
      }
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Here is the test I wrote for it.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

describe('useFocusOnElement', () => {
  let ref: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  let focusMock: jest.SpyInstance;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ref = { current: document.createElement('div') } as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
    focusMock = jest.spyOn(ref.current as HTMLDivElement, 'focus');
  });

  it('will call focus on passed ref after mount ', () => {
    expect(focusMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    renderHook(() => useFocusOnElement(ref));
    expect(focusMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I would like to also test for the case where `document` is undefined as we also do SSR. In the hook I am checking for the existence of `document` and I would like to test for both cases.

JSDOM included document so I feel I'd need to remove it and some how catch an error in my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `wrapWithGlobal` and `wrapWithOverride` from https://github.com/airbnb/jest-wrap.

```
describe('useFocusOnElement', () => {
  let ref: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  let focusMock: jest.SpyInstance;
  let activeElMock: unknown;
  let activeEl: HTMLDivElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const { window } = new JSDOM();
    global.document = window.document;
    activeEl = document.createElement('div');
    ref = { current: document.createElement('div') };
    focusMock = jest.spyOn(ref.current as HTMLDivElement, 'focus');
    activeElMock = jest.spyOn(activeEl, 'focus');
  });
  wrapWithOverride(
    () => document,
    'activeElement',
    () => activeEl,
  );
  describe('when document present', () => {
    it('will focus on passed ref after mount and will focus on previously active element on unmount', () => {
      const hook = renderHook(() => useFocusOnElement(ref));
      expect(focusMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
      hook.unmount();
      expect(activeElMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });

  describe('when no document present', () => {
    wrapWithGlobal('document', () => undefined);

    it('will not call focus on passed ref after mount nor on previously active element on unmount', () => {
      const hook = renderHook(() => useFocusOnElement(ref));
      expect(focusMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      hook.unmount();
      expect(activeElMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to simulate `document` as `undefined`, you should mock it like:

```js
jest
   .spyOn(global as any, 'document', 'get')
   .mockImplementationOnce(() => undefined);
```

But to this work in your test, you will need to set `spyOn` inside `renderHook` because looks like it also makes use of document internally, and if you set `spyOn` before it, you will get an error.

Working test example:

```js
it('will NOT call focus on passed ref after mount', () => {
    expect(focusMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    renderHook(() => {
      jest
        .spyOn(global as any, 'document', 'get')
        .mockImplementationOnce(() => undefined);

      useFocusOnElement(ref);
    });

    expect(focusMock).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by creating a second test file with a node environment:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

describe('useFocusOnElement server-side', () => {
  ...
});
```